# Powershell XML from XSD

Tags: xml, powershell

I've been searching around but haven't quite found my answer yet, so here goes (pardon me if my Google/SE-fu isn't working properly today)

I have a custom XSD for data that I would like to use when getting data from a PowerShell script.  I know how to manually convert an Export-CLIXml document to what I need, but that adds a lot of programming overhead.  Is there a way I can import my XSD as the schema standard for a new XML document to be written out?

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: So who would know the mapping even if you do import it?

Comment: the XSD would be provided and referenced in the script

Comment: You have some object which can be serialized as xml, now you coming up with another schema ( read class ) that you want to get. Who will tell your tool how to map former object to the new one?

Comment: I'm creating custom objects within Powershell.   The standard clixml template is not suitable for what I need.

Comment: use your xsd with xsd.exe, fill in instance of generated class with data you need, and serialize it to output ( ie file) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: there's no easy way to do that within powershell?

Comment: powershell gives you virtually all the same features .net gives you. If you want to get resulting xml you need some how to fill in corresponding data structure. you can do it using powershell or any other language within .net platform.

Comment: this process is not complicated, but can be labour intensive. That is why another option for you can be to generate "any" xml and use xslt to transform it to your schema. in this case you can use visual tools like Altova MapForce.